# How can I generate 100 random number of nodes from the whole graph Gephi Toolkit?

Tags: random, nodes, gephi

I'm working on a project and I'm using Gephi toolkit.I need to generate 100 random number of nodes from the whole graph.

```
public void script() {
        //Init a project - and therefore a workspace
        ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
        pc.newProject();
        Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();
 GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getGraphModel();
        PreviewModel model = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PreviewController.class).getModel();
        ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);
        FilterController filterController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(FilterController.class);
        AppearanceController appearanceController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(AppearanceController.class);
        AppearanceModel appearanceModel = appearanceController.getModel();

        //Import file       
        Container container;
        try {
           // File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/org/gephi/toolkit/demos/polblogs.gml").toURI());
           File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/org/gephi/toolkit/demos/Book3.csv").toURI()); 
           container = importController.importFile(file);
            container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDirectionDefault.DIRECTED);   //Force DIRECTED
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        //Append imported data to GraphAPI
        importController.process(container, new DefaultProcessor(), workspace);


        //See if graph is well imported
        DirectedGraph graph = graphModel.getDirectedGraph();
        System.out.println("Nodes: " + graph.getNodeCount());
        System.out.println("Edges: " + graph.getEdgeCount());
```

This code returns number of nodes and edges..but I can't find a function to extract a subset of nodes randomly...I need to print out number of nodes not all the nodes because i'm working on Genetic algorithm and i'm needing to generate initial population...please any idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a nicer way but you could use the `NodeIterator` returned from `graph.getNodes()`

Or use `graph.getNodes().toArray()` which will return an array of nodes.

You could then extract 100 random nodes from there making use of `Math.random`.

If you add your results to a set you can be sure that you aren't getting the same node more than once.

Not tested but something like this...

```
static final int POPULATION_SIZE = 100;
public Set<Node> getInitialPopulation(Graph graph){
    Node[] nodes = graph.getNodes().toArray();
    Set<Node> initialPopulation = new HashSet<>();
    if(nodes.length < POPULATION_SIZE){
        for(Node node : nodes){
            initialPopulation.add(node);
        }
        return initialPopulation;
    }

    while(initialPopulation.size() < POPULATION_SIZE){
        initialPopulation.add(nodes[(int)(Math.random()*nodes.length)]);
    }
    return initialPopulation;
}
```

Comment: Thank you..but can you help me in coding these lines please ?

Comment: Thank you very much,  but it doesn't work . The code doesn't recognize <HashSet>

Comment: It's part of the `java.util` package, you need to import it

Comment: And if its the diamond operators it's complaining about then I suggest you use a newer version of java or define it as `Set<Node> initialPopulation = new HashSet<Node>();`